# Has been HTTP 302 redirect modified

Tags: http, redirect, http-status-code-302, http-status-code-304

I think it is not possible, but I will ask experienced people for advice.

Imagine the situation:

1. A client send a request to get a content *A*, i.e. [www.server.com/content/1](http://www.server.com/content/1).
2. A server process the request, and generate a redirect link (every request = new link). A process of generating the redirect link is a quite expensive.
3. The server send response **302 Found** to the client. The response contains **Location**, **Expires**, **ETag** and **Last-Modified** headers and also payload with hypertext (https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.4.3).
4. The client is redirected to the new URL ([www.server2.com/c/212123123/1](http://www.server2.com/c/212123123/1)) where can obtain the content *A*.

When the client again send request to the server ([www.server.com/content/1](http://www.server.com/content/1)) - point #1 - the browser uses cached **302 Found** and instantly go to the URL from point #4 ([www.server2.com/c/212123123/1](http://www.server2.com/c/212123123/1)).

The point is, the cached **302 Found** can be outdated.
Intended behavior is that the client firstly send request with **If-Modified-Since** and **If-None-Match** headers to the server which has two options:

1. the URL is up-to-date = **send 304 Not Modified**
2. the URL is outdated and server regenerate the URL and send new **302 Found**

Than the client:

1. Use cached **302 Found** (server send **304 Not Modified**)
2. Use new **302 Found**

The question is: Is possible to check whether is **302 Found** still valid, i.e. server response with **304 Not Modified** or with new **302 Found**? A lot of time spend but it does not work. Thanks.